# PS3 controller shutting down during Lair of the Shadow Broker

Tags: ps3, controllers, mass-effect-2

I am having trouble trying to finish the "Lair of the Shadow Broker" in the *Mass Effect Trilogy* on the PS3. I am up to the part of chasing down Vasir in the transports, where you have to hold down the <kbd>L1</kbd> button to chase her down. Well, without warning, the controller just shuts itself off after holding the <kbd>L1</kbd> button for a few seconds, which causes the vehicle in the the game to just stop or spin in circles.  I did buy the game system with said controller pre-owned, but I don't know if that may be the issue, because it works fine with my other games, although I'm not holding the <kbd>L1</kbd> button down that much when I am playing them.

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried holding down L1 while not inside of a game? It is good practice to repeat the conditions of controller shut off outside of the game to try and isolate the error conditions.

Comment: I'd recommend testing other controllers, or if in the XMB, holding down L1 to see what it does.  If it shuts down anywhere else, it's not the game, it's the controller.

Answer (score 2):

As has been said, I would try using another game and repeat the process or do it out of game. If this does change the outcome, no problem. If this doesn't change the outcome try a friends pad or try your pad on a friends console (if you can with the same game at the same point).

If all else fails try contacting sony about the problem and see what they have to say.